# Annotation based transactions not working - spring 3

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions, annotations

I am trying to integrate hibernate into my first Spring web-project using annotation-based transactions. However, this does not work, as I notice on a save query not committing.

This is the aop configuration:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="package.names.project.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="package.names.project.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="package.names.common.util" />

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name="Logger" />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

<!-- the transactional advice (what 'happens'; see the <aop:advisor/> bean 
    below) -->
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
        <tx:method name="save" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Exception" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<!-- ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution of 
    an operation defined by a service in the service package -->
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceOperations" expression="execution(* package.names.project.dao.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceOperations" />
</aop:config>

<!-- similarly, don't forget the PlatformTransactionManager -->
<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>


<bean id="Logger" class="package.names.common.aop.Logger" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

I have the following hibernate configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="connection.password">pass</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
            <property name="connection.autocommit">true</property> 

    <mapping class="package.names.model.Person" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Bean declarations:

```
<bean id="personDao" class="package.names.project.dao.PersonDaoImpl"></bean>
<bean id="dbService" class="package.names.project.service.DbService"></bean>
```

My service layer looks like this

```
@Service("Service")

public class DbService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonDao personDao;

    public void setPersonDao(PersonDao personDao){
        this.personDao=personDao;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void save(Person person){
        personDao.save(person.getName(), person.getAge());
    }
    @Transactional
    public List<String> listPerson(){
        return personDao.listPerson();
    }
}
```

Changed the sessionFactory in my dao to an autowired one:

```
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory factory;

    public void setFactory(SessionFactory factory){
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public Long save(String personName, Integer personAge) {
        Long personId = null;
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        System.out.println( TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(personName);
        person.setAge(personAge);
        session.saveOrUpdate(person);
        session.close();
        return personId;
    }..
```

There are just no signs the transactions are committed. (No insert statements are shown while show-sql is true) There are no error messages to clearify it.

(if I add 'session.beginTransaction().commit()' to my save() function, it will work. But that seems against the principles of declarative transaction management.)

**UPDATE:**

The database connection works fine, as does the listPerson() method.

I can confirm transaction is active in the save method and that the save method is used by using

```
logger.info(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive())
```

And I can see autocommitting is set to true in the logging:

```
INFO: autocommit mode: true
```

I even created a service layer between the controller and the dao, to be sure it's not the dao layer causing problems. I used

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
```

to be sure the problem wasn't caused by a read-only mode.
What's left to try?

**UPDATE 2:**
Fixed the problem. It was caused by opening a new session each time the method save was called. Now I just use  factory.openSession() one time, after that I use factory.getCurrentSession() and I don't close the session.

Comment: You don't need to call `openSession` - Spring takes care of all of that for you.  Always just call `getSession`.

Answer (score 1):

> The default behavior for `ApplicationContext` implementations is to
>   eagerly pre-instantiate all singleton beans at startup.

Since your exception is complaining about eager-loading try adding `lazy-init="true"` attribute to your Spring beans.

**Example:**

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

For more information on *Lazy initialization* [see](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init).

**EDIT**

Also to resolve your commit issue, try adding below to your `datasource` settings:

```
<property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That does fix the last problem with the conflicting aop configurations.
The first problem still exists.

Comment: See Edited version of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To use `@Transactional` your bean must be accessed via Spring container. In provided sample I don't see anything that would show how this bean is created. You must have either

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package.names"/>
```

or

```
<bean class="package.names.PersonDaoImpl"/>
```

And then you would have to get bean from container either via autowiring or `getBean()`.

So how do you get your DAO bean instance in the application? Also it would be helpful to see bean class declaration as well as interface. I did have cases when transactional proxies are not properly created because of some specifc class relationships.